# Connection Pooling only triggered on home page hit - ASP.NET MVC5 Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

I really feel silly asking this question but I can't seem to figure this out - even though it sounds trivial.

The problem arises when my site goes idle and the connection pool is closed - if I try to access a page **other** than the homepage, I am receiving the YSOD stating

'*A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server*'

I tried to debug the controller action being called but it doesn't even get hit... and I have no idea where else I could place a break point to see what's trying to be called.

I can see the connection dropping off with a sp_who and coming back up when the home page is hit.

I'm using ASP.NET MVC5 along with Entity Framework 6. I haven't specified any setting for connection pooling since it's on by default with EF. I'm also wrapping all my DB contexts in using blocks.

Has anyone any idea what would cause this or even where to begin looking in regards to debugging this?

I think that forms authentication may be responsible for this - but then again, surely if that timed out I'd be redirected to the default Account/Login route that MVC5 sets you up with when beginning a new project.

**UPDATE**
I was able to fix this by adding the the SimpleRoleProvider to the webconfig in:

```
    <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="SimpleRoleProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="SimpleRoleProvider" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" type="WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleRoleProvider, WebMatrix.WebData" />
     </providers>
   </roleManager>
```

Then I had to move:

```
WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("DefaultConnection", "UserProfile", "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);
```

into my Global.cs so that it was the first thing called.

Comment: Are you using the standard/default MVC 5 authentication?

Comment: Hi Kieth, yes I am indeed. I left that code in from when I created the project. Is there a known issue with this?

Comment: No, no known issue. I was asking to eliminate avenues of exploration. I'd try setting a breakpoint on `ApplicationDbContext` constructor to see what is happening in there.

Comment: On further inspection, it looks like the YSOD could be from another site on my machine since the w3wp.exe process for my MVC app is not even running! It's only being triggered when the homepage is entered in a browser.

Comment: ignore above, I can see the worker request for the app pool in IIS but it won't wake the w3wp.exe under the app pool

Comment: Found it, missing the role provider in web config...

Comment: Please post what you found and mark it as the answer so that future searches might find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this by adding the the SimpleRoleProvider to the webconfig in:

```
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="SimpleRoleProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="SimpleRoleProvider" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" type="WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleRoleProvider, WebMatrix.WebData" />
 </providers>
</roleManager>
```

Then I had to move:

```
WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("DefaultConnection", "UserProfile", "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);
```

out of InitializeSimpleMembershipAttribute.cs into my Global.cs so that it was the first thing called.